# Recylerview doesn't show fetched data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I make an api call to get a list, in the logcat I can see all the groups that came back from the api but the Recylerview doesn't show my items.

ViewModel

```
class MyGroupScreenViewMode(private val context: Context, private val codagramApi: CodagramApi) : ViewModel() {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val myGroups = MutableLiveData<List<Group>>()


    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun getMyGroups(): LiveData<List<Group>> = myGroups


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val response = codagramApi.getAllGroups()
            updateUi(response.groupList)
        }
    }
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private fun updateUi(update: List<Group>){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            myGroups.value = update
        }
    }
```

and the fragment

```
class MyGroupScreen : Fragment() {
    private val myGroupsAdapter: GroupAdapter by inject()
    private lateinit var bindingGroup: FragmentThirdBinding

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val viewModel: MyGroupScreenViewMode by inject()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        bindingGroup = FragmentThirdBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        return bindingGroup.root
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        bindingGroup.myGroups.apply {
            adapter = this@MyGroupScreen.myGroupsAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        }
        myGroupsAdapter.currentList

        bindingGroup.fabAdd.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(MyGroupScreenDirections.actionFirstViewToGroupscreen())
        }
        bindgetmyGroupToLiveData()

    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private fun bindgetmyGroupToLiveData() {
        viewModel.getMyGroups().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, androidx.lifecycle.Observer {
            myGroupsAdapter.submitList(it)
        })
    }
```

and the adapter

```
class GroupAdapter : ListAdapter<Group,GroupScreenViewHolder>(object: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Group>(){

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Group, newItem: Group): Boolean = oldItem.creator?.id == newItem.creator?.id


    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Group, newItem: Group): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem

}) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroupScreenViewHolder {
        return GroupScreenViewHolder(
            GroupscreenMygroupsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroupScreenViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(getItem(position))

    }
}
    class GroupScreenViewHolder(private val binding: GroupscreenMygroupsBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        fun bind(postData: Group) {

            binding.textView.text = postData.id.toString()


        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Firstly, please edit your question properly and re-post it because the half class is shown as text and other half is shown as "code snippet", so it is difficult to understand. Please post the code snippet properly. . 2.Secondly, cross check whther the data is getting properly passed in class `GroupAdapter `. Add the following Log statement inside `fun bind`: Log.d("GroupAdapter_Class","$postData.id.toString()") and check whether the data gets printed in logcat or not. This might give you idea whether your adapter is getting data or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check if data is in the list, then assign the list to adapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),